# PKCS#7 Padding Issue with AES Encryption in C

Tags: c#, c, aes, pkcs#7

This has been solved, I included the solution code at the bottom of the post.

There are two programs in Python and C#, and I am trying to make a version of it in C. I am trying to create a function that encrypts text using AES-256 in CBC mode, using the [Tiny AES Library](https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c). I have put the Python and C#, as well as my own C code below.

Python Code

```
import os
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import (algorithms, modes, Cipher)
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.padding import PKCS7

text = "6bcdax94cvrdnhvo"
key = "7copiqupo7cpaq7c9u7qab84rpc16gvk"

encodedText = text.encode()
encodedKey = key.encode()

iv = encodedKey[:16]

cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(encodedKey), modes.CBC(iv))
encryptor = cipher.encryptor()

padder = PKCS7(128).padder()
pad = padder.update(encodedText) + padder.finalize()
print(encryptor.update(pad))
```

C# Code

```
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

string text = "6bcdax94cvrdnhvo";
string key = "7copiqupo7cpaq7c9u7qab84rpc16gvk";

byte[] byteKey= Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);

Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create();
aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
aesAlg.Key = byteKey;
aesAlg.IV = byteKey[0..16];

ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
byte[] encrypted = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text), 0, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text).Length);
encryptor.Dispose();

string plainText = BitConverter.ToString(encrypted);
plainText = plainText.Replace("-", "");

Console.WriteLine($@"{plainText}");
```

C Code

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "aes.h"

int main()
{
    uint8_t text[16] = "6bcdax94cvrdnhvo";
    uint8_t key[32] = "7copiqupo7cpaq7c9u7qab84rpc16gvk";
    uint8_t iv[16];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        iv[i] = key[i];
    }

    struct AES_ctx ctx;

    AES_init_ctx_iv(&ctx, key, iv);
    AES_CBC_encrypt_buffer(&ctx, text, 16);

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        printf("%.2x", text[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Both the Python and C# programs print "9192D9DACF7E02D06F00DB82DFED3E3764C159683BE158F76D95114288F512EA" to the standard output (console).

While my C program prints "9192d9dacf7e02d06f00db82dfed3e37" and increasing the length of the for loop doesnt return the correct value, only random other hex data e.g (9192d9dacf7e02d06f00db82dfed3e3737636f70697175706f37637061713763).

To be clear the issue is the difference between the last 16 characters between the program outputs.
Its should be - 9192D9DACF7E02D06F00DB82DFED3E37**64C159683BE158F76D95114288F512EA**
But it is actually - 9192d9dacf7e02d06f00db82dfed3e37**37636f70697175706f37637061713763**

I have tried to research as much as possible and I think the issue is something to do with PKCS#7 padding, but I am not entirely sure.

Any help with achieving the desired output would be great, thank you in advance.

Edit: Fixed bold text

Comment: Strings in C need room for the null termination or otherwise they aren't strings, see the linked duplicate. That is, `text[16]` -> `text[16+1]` and so on.

Comment: I understand that, but changing the values by 1 as you have stated doesn't fix the fundamental problem I am having.

I think the issue is more than just not enough room to store the string.

A proper look at the code is needed to understand the issue.

Comment: The Python code pads explitly, the C# code implicitly (in both cases with [PKCS#7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7)). Since your plaintext is one block in size (16 bytes), PKCS#7 adds a whole block of padding bytes so that the resulting ciphertext is 32 bytes large. There is no padding in the C code ([tiny-AES-c](https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c) doesn't support padding, s. *Important notes*), which is why the ciphertext is only 16 bytes (increasing the size of the loop will only show uninitialized memory, resulting in random values).

Comment: Actually I peeked closed to your lib and it says `Function AES_init_ctx_iv(struct AES_ctx *, const uint8_t *, const uint8_t *)`. So `uint8_t` and not `char`, indeed I might have closed this prematurely. Sorry, will re-open! (You should still fix the string bugs though or they'll come back to bite you sooner or later.)

Comment: If you compare the results again you'll notice that the results start to differ after the first 16 bytes of hex - you've marked the wrong part as bold. Why I suspected that null termination could be the culprit.

Comment: Did you edit "aes.h" to override the default key size to 256 bits.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes the file is set too ```#define AES256 1```, if it wasnt the first 16 characters of the printed string would not be correct.

It seems like the issue isnt anything to do with Tiny AES, as @Topaco said, it doesnt support padding.

So we need to find a way to add the padding.

Comment: Possibly interesting for you: [Tiny AES in CBC mode with PKCS7 padding written in C](https://erev0s.com/blog/tiny-aes-cbc-mode-pkcs7-padding-written-c/).

Comment: @Topaco Maybe I should have mentioned this in the original post, but I tried that already. If you scroll to the bottom of the page you linked, there is an example box titled "An example of output is presented below:"

The example box contains the output of the test program, there is a line that says:

```The padded STRING in hex is = 6d7920737570657220736563726574207468696e672074686174206e6565647320746f2072656d61696e207468617420776179210c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c```

If you notice all the function does is pad the hex value up to the nearest 16 value with random data, in this case "0c".

Comment: The 0x0c are not random data, but the PKCS#7 padding bytes, whose value specifies the number of padding bytes, in the example 0x0c = 12 padding bytes. If the plaintext  size already corresponds to an integer multiple of the blocksize (16 bytes), PKCS#7 appends a complete padding block, i.e. 16 times 0x10 values (= 16 padding bytes). This applies to your plaintext. If you encrypt the padded data with your code, the ciphertext is the same as that of the Python or C# code.

Comment: More specifically: If you encrypt with your code `uint8_t text[] = "6bcdax94cvrdnhvo\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10\x10"`, you get the ciphertext of the Python/C# code.

Comment: @Topaco I understand now, I updated the post with new code, it works as expected without the need for that library. Thank you so much, your explanation helped me. This can be marked as closed now, I cant do it because there is no answer for me to select.

Comment: @MrWicked glad you got your solution. You could move your final/correct code to an _answer_ that _you_ create. You can then accept your own answer. This will clue others that the issue is resolved. In such circumstances, self-answered questions are encouraged on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem by manually inserting the 0x10 values into the end of the array.

```
int main()
{
    uint8_t text[32 + 1] = "6bcdax94cvrdnhvo";
    uint8_t key[32 + 1] = "7copiqupo7cpaq7c9u7qab84rpc16gvk";
    uint8_t iv[16 + 1];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        if (i >= 16) {
            text[i] = 0x10;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        iv[i] = key[i];
    }

    struct AES_ctx ctx;

    AES_init_ctx_iv(&ctx, key, iv);
    AES_CBC_encrypt_buffer(&ctx, text, 32);

    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        printf("%.2x", text[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```